# Can $\sum_{k\in M}\frac{1}{k}$ be a large integer?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm interested in the following question:

Given an integer $n_0$. Is there always an integer $n>n_0$ and a **finite** subset $M\subset \mathbb N$ with $\sum_{k\in M}\frac{1}{k} = n$.

This is not a homework problem, I don't know if there is an easy solution.
I appreciate any hint.

Comment: It is known that $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$ is no integer for $n>1$. So at least that shows us that $M$ can't be an initial segment of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: I am a complete non-expert, but you might find some partial answers here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sums_of_reciprocals and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31768/sums-of-reciprocals-of-primes-can-be-integers.  Would be interested to hear an expert's view.

Comment: no idea; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction#Modern_number_theory

Comment: This might work: Let $N$ be some number between $n$ and $n+1$ with $N = \sum_{k\in M} 1/n$, and let $q = n + 1 - N$. Decompose $q$ into its Egyptian fraction decomposition, and use the identity $\frac1a = \frac{1}{a+1} + \frac{1}{a(a+1)}$ until the smallest denominator is greater than the largest element of $M$. Then this new set can be added to $M$ to produce a set $S$ with $\sum_{k\in S} 1/k = N + q = n+1$.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams Why does such a decomposition of $q$ exist?

Comment: @user148177, it is a well known theorem proven by Fibonacci. "Fibonacci proved that any fraction can be represented as a sum of distinct unit fractions" (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EgyptianFraction.html).

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams Can't we just use this result to represent $n_0+1$ as an Egyptian fraction?

Comment: @LeBtz precisely.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams Are you sure that is a finite process in the given reference?  I can't chase it further.

Comment: @user148177, yes. [See for example.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions#Algorithm_and_examples)

Comment: Well i would like to accept your comment then. If you want you can post an answer :-)

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams I question it because in the next sentence it talks about constructing an infinite sum.  Do you have a reference that's a little more fleshed out?

Comment: @user148177, at the Wikipedia article I linked, it is clear that the numerator of the fraction in Fibonacci's algorithm is always decreasing, and hence the algorithm terminates.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams Thank you very much!

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams Ah, I see.  Seems like an answer to me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, and more is true: given *any positive rational number* $n$, there exists a finite set $M\subset\Bbb N$ such that $\sum_{k\in M} \frac1k = n$.

Perhaps the most straightforward proof is this: since the harmonic series diverges, there exists a unique $m\in\Bbb N$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m \frac1k \le n < \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac1k.
$$
(If $n$ is small then $m$ might equal $0$.)
Write $r=n-\sum_{k=1}^m \frac1k$, which is a rational number less than $\frac1{m+1}$. Then use the [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions) to write $r$ as an Egyptian fraction $\sum_{k\in M_r} \frac1k$. By size considerations, every element of $M_r$ exceeds $m$, and so $M=\{1,\dots,m\} \cup M_r$ has the property that $\sum_{k\in M} \frac1k = n$.

Similar constructions can yield representations of $n$ with particular constraints; for example, one can choose any $j\in\Bbb N$ and force all the elements of $M$ to exceed $j$.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly for any $n_0$ there exists a (not necessarily integer) $N$ and a set $S$ such that $n \le N < n + 1 $ by the divergence of the harmonic series with:
$$ N = \sum_{k \in S} \frac1k $$

Let $ q = n + 1 - N $. It is well known that there exists a finite decomposition of $q$ into [unit fractions with unique denominators](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EgyptianFraction.html) (call the multiset of such $Q$). Using the identity:

$$ \frac{1}{a} = \frac{1}{a+1} + \frac{1}{a(a+1)}$$

we can make the denominators in $Q$ larger than the largest element of $S$. (We have to be careful how we do this, but clearly it is possible.) Since $Q$ is finite, this process terminates. Now $Q \cup S $ is the desired set with $\sum_{k \in Q \cup S} \frac1k = n + 1$, and $Q \cap S = \emptyset$.

Comment: Why is it clearly possible? Why can duplicates be avoided?

Comment: @joriki I wondered the same thing, but you can continue to use $\frac{1}{a}=\frac{1}{a+1}+\frac{1}{a(a+1)}$ whenever there is a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidHill: I thought so at first, too, but I don't see how it's guaranteed that this process doesn't keep producing duplicates. It seems plausible that it might work, but I don't see an argument that qualifies for "clearly".

Comment: @DavidHill In each step you get one element more to take care of. So it's not clear why this process should terminate.

Comment: It still seems to me that even if you get another element to take care of, it shouldn't be difficult to deal with since it eventually won't be a duplicate (once it gets larger than the largest element of the initial set). Still, a formal proof might be a little hard to supply. (I guess the question is, given a rational $r$, can we find a decomposition with arbitrarily large denominators.) Personally, I would much rather have Greg's answer below accepted.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain you are right.

Answer (score 2):

The [Erdős–Graham conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Graham_problem) in combinatorial number theory states that, if the unit fractions are partitioned into finitely many subsets, then one of the subsets has a finite subset of itself whose reciprocals sum to one.

That would imply that we can write every positive integer as sum of unit fractions: We show that we can construct a sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of disjoint finite subsets of $\mathbb N\setminus \{1\}$ such that $\sum_{i\in A_n} \frac{1}{i}=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. We construct the sequence by induction: Let $n\ge 1$ be given and $A_1 ,\dots A_n$ be already defined. We split each of those $A_i$ in two non-empty set and define
$$B:=\mathbb N \setminus \left( \{1\} \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right).$$
Then those $2n+1$ sets are a partition of $\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}$. By the stated conjecture $B$ contains a finite subset $B'$ such that $\sum_{i\in B'} \frac{1}{i}=1$. We define $A_{n+1}:=B'$.

In order to write a given positive integer $n$ as sum of unit fractions we simply define
$$S:= \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i $$
and have 
$$\sum_{i\in S} \frac{1}{i}=n.$$

Comment: Does it really imply that?  I feel like there are many steps missing here.

Comment: @user148177 If you want, I can fill the gaps.

Comment: Please do; note you can't simply multiply the representation by $n$ because that would turn your reciprocals into fractions.  Repeated fractions are also not allowed.

Comment: @user148177 Done.

Comment: I think the conjecture would state that *one* of the pieces of the partition has a finite subset summing to one, not all of them.  In your inductive step, since all the $A_i$ already sum to one, one can't conclude that $B$ has a subset that will sum to one.

Comment: @user148177 Nope. I split the $A_i$ into two sets to ensure that they don't contain such a subset.

Comment: Ah okay, seems good.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X02927976) there are even infinitely many numbers $n$ that can be written as sum of unit fractions. It provides a divergent lower bound on the number $|N(n)|$ of integers that can be written as the sum of unit fractions whose denominator is at most $n$.

Another paper on this topic can be found [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X83710152). It states that the [splitting algorithm](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/numth/egypt/conflict.html) terminates for every positive rational. This means that *every positive integer* admits a representation as the sum of unit fractions.

These papers show that the result you're asking for is true, but I don't know if there is any elementary proof of this theorem.

Comment: Does this allow for repeats? It seems like it must, since the harmonic series diverges only logarithmically.

Comment: Indeed, I think the first sentence is a misquoting of the paper's result.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I've misinterpreted the statement of the paper. It should be correct now.